# How to Public Set - Public Declared variables?

Tags: excel, variables, vba

I have a separate module to declare public variables

```
Public ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
```

On each module, on each procedure I must repeat the following :

```
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sun")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Moon")
```

...and then - write the code.

So, WHERE and HOW can I Set this variables so they are allready set on each module, on each Sub or Function - as Sheets Sun and Moon ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have it set it will remain available to the other modules. So I suggest you set it on `Workbook_Open`. Also your current code does not dimension `ws1` as a worksheet, so I suggest you use

**`Standard Module`**

```
Public ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
```

**`ThisWorkbook Module`**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sun")
End Sub
```

Comment: ThankYou, brettdj. Are you sure about comma separated declaration. I Have string variables declared as (for example) -  `Poblic a, b, c, d, As String` and they all works ?

Comment: @Alegro.  He's sure. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx Scroll down to "Pay Attention To Variables Declared With One Dim Statement"

Comment: Ok, it's clear. Thanks brettdj and Doug. Stack Owerflow is a really nice place.